# Task vs Barrier

Tags: c#, task, barrier

So my problem is as follows: I have a list of items to process and I'd like to process the items in parallel then commit the processed items.

The barrier class in C# will allow me to do this - I can run threads in parallel to process the list of items and when SignalAndWait is called and all participants hit he barrier I can commit the processed items.

The Task class will also allow me to do this - on the Task.WaitAll call I can wait for all tasks to complete and I can commit the processed items. If I understand correctly each task will run on it's own thread not a bunch of tasks in parallel on the same thread.

1. Is my understand correct on both usages for the problem?
2. Is there any advantage between one over the other?
3. Is there any way a hybrid solution is better (barrier and tasks?).

Comment: Never knew of `Barrier`.  Upon reading it perhaps _TPL Dataflow_ is more to your liking?

Comment: When you process your data, are you doing IO bound work or CPU bound work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is my understand correct on both usages for the problem?

I think you have a misunderstanding of the `Barrier` class. [The docs say](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997287%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> A barrier is a **user-defined synchronization primitive** that enables multiple threads (known as participants) to work concurrently on an algorithm in phases.

A barrier is a synchronization primitive. Comparing it to  a unit of work which may be computed in parallel such as a `Task` isn't correct.

A barrier can signal all threads to wait until all others have completed some work and check upon that work. By itself, it has no parallel computation capabilities and no threading model behind it.

> Is there any advantage between one over the other?

As for question 1, you see this is irrelevant.

> Is there any way a hybrid solution is better (barrier and tasks?).

In your case, I'm not sure its needed at all. If you sinply want to do CPU bound computation in parallel on a collection of items, you have [`Parallel.ForEach`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.parallel.foreach%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) exactly for that purpose. It will partition an enumerable and invoke them in parallel, and block until the entire collection has been computed.

Comment: Great answer I understand the difference, now what if I told you that I was using EF for example to pull back information and run calculations then once processed - I would commit processed records. In your example I would get the items to be processed and run calculations using Parallel.foreach?

Comment: @Pr0ph3t Yes. I would query the data from EF (either synchronously or asynchronously, whichever you choose) and once the data is loaded in memory, I would use `Parallel.ForEach` to run those computations. You can also look into [PLINQ](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460688%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which may fit your needs.

Comment: Looks like there may be other issues with Parallel.ForEach and EF - but that's another topic.

Comment: @Pr0ph3t You shouldn't use `Parallel.ForEach` for the query part of your operation! Use it after you've queried the data. If you need to concurrently hit your database, look into the async API exposed by EF.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not directly answering your question because I think that working with barriers and tasks is just making your code more complex than it needs to be.

I'd suggest using Microsoft's Reactive Framework for this - NuGet "Rx-Main" - as it just makes the whole problem super simple.

Here's the code:

```
var query =
    from item in items.ToObservable()
    from processed in Observable.Start(() => processItem(item))
    select new { item, processed };

query
    .ToArray()
    .Subscribe(processedItems =>
    {
        /* commit the processed items */
    });
```

The query turns a list of items into a observable and then processes each item using `Observable.Start(...)`. This optimally fires off new threads as needed. The `.ToArray()` takes the sequence of individual results and changes it into a single array of results. The `.Subscribe(...)` method then allows you to process the results.

The code is much simpler than using tasks or barriers.

Comment: But does he really need the data in a streaming matter? Not sure. Also, I don't see how working with tasks or `Parallel.ForEach` is less complex than Rx?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov - What do you mean by a "streaming matter"?

Comment: Rx will stream the output to `Subscribe` as the query completes.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov - The `.ToArray()` will collect all of the values and pass them all out at once. This is what the OP wanted.